# Get legacy CAS Model value programmatically in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-4.5, code-access-security

I use VS 2012 and ASP.NET 4.5.

How can I know if ***legacy CAS model*** is enabled `programmatically` in C# (executing my code in ASP.NET 2.0 - CLR 2.0 , and ASP.NET 4.5 (CLR 4.0) ? and which **level** ?

```
<system.web>

    <trust legacyCasModel="true" level="Full"/>

  </system.web>

 <runtime>

    <NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true"/>

  </runtime>
```

Comment: There is no public API for retrieving this information, although there are workarounds.  It would be easier to suggest an appropriate approach if you could describe how you are planning on using the information.  Also, what exactly do you mean by "level" (e.g.: policy level, transparency level, etc.)?

Comment: **level** value like `Full`

Comment: The "full" type "level" really only has two named alternatives: fully trusted or partially trusted.  Is this what you mean?  Also, you still haven't described what you want to do with this information once you have it...

Comment: ***Diagnostics reasons***, know if a web site has legacyCasModel or not

Answer (score 2):

you can read it by the following code in **web** application (I have tested it in .Net 4.7.1 and VS 2017):

```
using System.Web.Configuration;

var trustsection = ((System.Web.Configuration.TrustSection)
                   WebConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/trust"));

bool isLegacyCasModel = trustsection.LegacyCasModel;
string level = trustsection.Level;
```

And for **console** application, I only found this way (which is not prefect, I believe) :

Note : I assumed that you enabled CAS policy in the following way, if you have set it with `NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy` tag, you can change the code respectively)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>    
    <legacyCasPolicy enabled="true" />
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

So the c# code will be :

```
    var xml = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None).GetSection("runtime").SectionInformation.GetRawXml();
    var doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(xml);

    bool isCasMode = doc.GetElementsByTagName("legacyCasPolicy")?[0]?.Attributes?["enabled"]?.Value == "true";
```